# Is it possible to bypass the local filesystem completely using an alternative filesystem?

Tags: 7, files, cdn

I'm using a cloud hosting provider to host a Drupal site (7 moving to 8) with a huge amount of static file assets. The host charges a lot for file space.

Is there a way to bypass the local filesystem entirely using a third-party file storage system? Success stories most welcome!

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

[Google drive field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_gdrive) - Have never tried it. But it should do the job.

[S3 file storrage](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) - This is for amazon file-storage.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion -- will give a try and report back.